# How were the White Walkers planning on getting through The Wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones

> In "Beyond the Wall" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E06), The Night King killed Viserion and turned him into an undead dragon. In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07), the Night King rode on Viserion's back to the Wall, where Viserion proceeded to breathe blue fire upon it, eventually melting and toppling it. This allowed the army of White Walkers and wights to cross the barrier that has kept them out of Westeros.

Before that happened, how were they planning on getting through the Wall?

Comment: Who's to say the Night King doesn't have greensight like Bran/Three-eyed raven, and can therefore foresee future events like Daenerys arriving with her three dragons? It certainly fits with all the odd events like him seemingly waiting for her and planning the whole thing, as well as his interactions with Bran. We don't know enough about the Night King and the White Walkers to know their plan.

Comment: `the barrier that has kept them out of Westeros` They were always in [Westeros](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Westeros), as the Lands of Always Winter is part of the continent.

Comment: [The Horn of Joramun](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Horn_of_Winter#Legend)

Comment: One thing that had people speculating was that, in the opening credits, the map/model of Eastwatch showed a lot more solid ice than in earlier seasons. The Night King maybe had to wait for a real, deep, long winter (waiting for centuries) to take hold because only that kind of winter could freeze enough sea ice for his army to march *around* the Wall.

Comment: Related question on [scifi.se]: **[Would the Night King have been able to succeed on his own?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/168425/21267)**

Comment: remember World War Z fellas???

Answer (score 4):

There are two possibilities. The most simple answer is that they had another method prepared. Finding a way around the edge somehow seems plausible, considering they were marching on the coast.

The other possibility is that there is some sort of prophetic ability involved. Recall how the Night King sees Bran and touches him as he uses greensight. More recently, the Hound sees a vision of the army (and Bran sees them through ravens), prompting Jon and Co. to travel there and subsequently send for help from Daenerys. If the Night King is in tune with these powers, the return of the White Walkers may have been planned entirely around this moment. They may have been waiting all these thousands of years for an opportunity to lure a dragon over the wall in winter.

Answer (score 1):

They would have attacked the wall just like the wildlings did. It would have taken longer, but eventually they would have gotten through.

Comment: A bit more description is needed in this answer.

Comment: I disagree. We saw a very successful attack on the wall that would have succeeded if Stannis had not shown up. No further description needed.

Comment: Pure speculation with no valid supporting sources.

Comment: This question calls for speculation. It is asking what would have happened.

Comment: Exactly - so don't answer questions to which the only answers can be pure speculation that is practically baseless. For all we know the Night King is Bran Stark or otherwise has greensight and predicted the whole thing and waited for her arrival. We don't know enough, yet, to do any speculation that is anything but weak, regarding this exact topic.

Comment: @BenjaminCuningham - The wildings were not bound or blocked by runes and magic carved into the wall at the time of its creation, so it could not have been anything similar to how the wildlings mounted their attack, both in front and from behind at the same time.

Comment: That is a good point. I guess I just don't see a huge difference between undead giants and an undead dragon. If the magic wall could stop one, why not stop the other?

Comment: @GhotiandChips Sorry, I did not realize that opinion based questions and answers were discouraged. I see your point now.

Answer (score -4):

The army of the dead will pass the wall thru the ice dragon(Viscerion) mounted by the Night King. It's ice breath will destroy the wall.

Comment: No, the OP's point is how were they expecting to cross at first, like without Viserion?